# How can I power a driveshaft while also allowing it to freely spin when not under power?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm designing a drill powered vehicle that needs to be able to drive uphill and downhill. [The drive train roughly looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6siG.jpg). The drill locks up when it's not running so I need something that will allow the shaft to freely spin when the power is off. I looked into centrifugal clutches but my drill doesn't produce high enough rpm for that to work.

Is there anything else that I could purchase or manufacture that would make this possible?

Answer (score 4):

yes, it is called a freewheel and most bicycle rear hubs have them, so you can coast without having to pedal the bike. in the mechanical engineering world, this is called an overrunning clutch.

Comment: A good example is found in starter motors for cars... basically works with a ball bearing or roller and an inclined plane...

Comment: See also : 'sprag clutch'.